# Действие выполняется не асинхронно

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Использую **Vue.js** + **Vuex**.

Имеется мутация

```
export function run (state, payload) {
  ...
}
```

, в которой, к примеру, рекрсивно считывается директория через **fs.readdirSync(dir)**.

Имеется действие

```
export function run (context, payload) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    context.commit('run', payload)
    resolve()
  })
}
```

В компоненте вызываю действие

```
this.run({
  path:     this.path,
  symbols:  this.symbols
}).then(()=>
  console.log('GOOD: ')
).catch((err)=>
  console.log('BAD: ')
).finally(()=> {
  console.log('FINALLY ')
})
```

На мой взгляд, после вызова действия **this.run** должно начаться считывание директории, но при этом работа приложения **не должна приостанавливаться**.

Как запускать код в мутации, так сказать "в параллельном потоке"?

P.S. Про асинхронный fs.readdir знаю, но данную задачу требуется(хочу) решить именно через синхронные функции.

Answer (score 0):

> Асинхронность в сочетании с мутацией состояний может сильно усложнить вашу программу. Например, когда вы вызываете два метода, оба с асинхронными обратными вызовами, которые изменяют состояние, как вы узнаете, когда они были вызваны и какой обратный вызов был вызван первым? Именно поэтому мы хотим разделить две концепции.
> **В Vuex [мутации](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html) - это синхронные транзакции** :
>
> Чтобы обрабатывать асинхронные операции, давайте введем [Actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html) .

[Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)